# Limit of improper integrals of uniformly convergent function

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

I've got a problem.

Let  $g(t)\ge0$ and it has improper integral on interval $[A, B)$.
Furthermore, sequence of integrable functions $f_{n}(t)$ is uniformly convergent do $f(t)$ on every subinterval $[a,b]$ of $[A,B)$ and
$0 \le f_{n}(t) \le g(t)$ for every $t\in[A,B)$

Prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{A}^{B^{-}}f_{n}(t)dt = \int_{A}^{B^{-}}f(t)dt$$

As I suppose our goal is to show that the difference

$$|\int_{A}^{B^{-}}f_{n}(t)dt-\int_{A}^{B^{-}}f(t)dt| < \epsilon$$

I've tried to do it like this

$$|\int_{A}^{B^{-}}f_{n}(t)dt-\int_{A}^{B^{-}}f(t)dt| =  |\int_{A}^{b}f_{n}(t)dt-\int_{A}^{b}f(t)dt + \int_{b}^{B^{-}}f_{n}(t)dt - \int_{b}^{B^{-}}f(t)dt| \le$$

$$\le \int_{A}^{b}|f_{n}(t)-f(t)|dt + |\int_{b}^{B^{-}}(f_{n}(t)-f(t))|$$

From the uniformly convergence we can make this first integral infitesimal $(b-A)\epsilon$, but don't know how to estimate the second one. As I think it has to be connected with function $g(t)$, but is it correct to say it is lower than $2\int_{b}^{B^{-}}g(t)dt$, which we can make infinitesimal, because of convergence of improper integral $\int_{A}{B^{-}}g(t)dt$.

Edit:

Okey, that's my last try

From uniform convergence of $f_{n}(t)$ to $f(t)$
We can make the difference $|f_{n}(t)-f(t)| < \epsilon_1 = \frac{\epsilon}{3(b-A)}$ then

$$\int_{A}^{b}|f_{n}(t)-f(t)|dt < (b-A)\cdot\epsilon_1 = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$$

Next step, it is known that our improper integral of $g(t)$ exists, so

$$\lim_{b\to B}\int_{b}^{B}g(t)dt = 0$$

Hence, we can make $|\int_{b}^{B}g(t)dt| < \epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

To sum up

$$\int_{A}^{b}|f_{n}(t)-f(t)|dt + |\int_{b}^{B^{-}}(f_{n}(t)-f(t))| \le (b-A)\cdot\epsilon_1 + 2\epsilon_2 = 3\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon$$

Comment: Can you bound $\lvert f_n(t) - f(t)\rvert$ using $g(t)$ for a fixed $t$?

Comment: In this specific context, I don't suppose you are supposed to use it, but there is a theorem that says exactly that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: Yes on your last sentence. You're very close!

Comment: Basically, you're there. However, you first need to pick $b$ so that $\int_b^{B^-} g(t)\,dt$ is small enough, then use the uniform convergence on $[A,b]$ to pick an $N$ so that $\int_A^b \lvert f_n(t) - f(t)\rvert\,dt$ is small enough for $n \geqslant N$. Note, by the way, that from $0 \leqslant f_n(t) \leqslant g(t)$ and the pointwise convergence it follows that also $0 \leqslant f(t) \leqslant g(t)$, and therefore $\lvert f_n(t) - f(t)\rvert \leqslant g(t)$. So you can drop the factor $2$ from the tail integral.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just cleaning up the original poster's answer, and formalizing Daniel Fischer's good hints in the comments, for anyone who wants all the details.

The limit we're trying to prove is equivalent to showing,
$\left| \int_A^{B-} f-f_n \right| < \epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

We have
$\left| \int_A^{B-} f-f_n \right| \le \left| \int_A^{b} f-f_n \right| + \left| \int_b^{B-} f-f_n \right|$.

By the bounds on $f$ and $f_n$ with respect to $g$, we have $|f-f_n| \le g(x)$, so,

$\left| \int_b^{B-} f-f_n \right| \le \int_b^{B-} |f-f_n| \le \int_b^{B-} g < \lim_{c \uparrow B} \int_b^c g $. (The last inequality follows from $g\ge0$.)

Now choose $b$ sufficiently large such that $\int_b^{B} g < \epsilon/2$ (as guaranteed by the integrability of $g$).

With $b$ now fixed, we have for all $n$ sufficiently large that, by uniform convergence of $f_n \to f$,
$\left| \int_A^b f-f_n \right| < \epsilon/2$. We can conclude that for all $n$ sufficiently large,
$\left| \int_A^{B-} f-f_n \right| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2$. Taking the limit in $n$ gives,
$\left| \int_A^{B-} f-\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_A^{B-} f_n \right| < \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, 
$\int_A^{B-} f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_A^{B-} f_n$.

~~~

(Edited slightly to include $\int_b^{B-} g < \lim_{c \uparrow B} \int_b^c g$; why the downvote? also including a comment is more helpful for the community, and for those making good faith efforts.)